# Duplicate identifier 'ResizeObserverCallback'

Tags: angular, node-modules, ng-zorro-antd, resize-observer

I got this errors when I use some Antd libraries such as table component, I have a Resize-observer file that I did by myself and its conflicting with this files, are there any ways to exclude the library resize-observer ?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rXu3.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite explicit.

`external-libs/ResizeObserver.d.ts` and `resize-observer-polyfill/src/index.d.ts` are duplicate definitions.

You should delete either one on them, I'd advise you to remove your local definition.